# Where moved to trash files go?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hue

I have the following questions regarding the "move to trash" functionality in the hue GUI:

1. Where do these files go?
2. How long are they stored?
3. Can I restore them?

Comment: @MaxNevermid: hue will interact with hdfs and default hdfs configurations will be applicable. Hue is just a client interface. You can write java client also to operate HDFS.(classes like FileSystem) will support. So I mean, client doesn't matter here.

Comment: If you are okay with my answer pls flagup "accepted by owner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `/user/hduser/.Trash`
Where hduser is unix(operating system user, it can be windows user also if you are using java client from windows + eclipse ) user. 
[image]
2) This will depend on the below configuration in core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
  <value>30</value>
  <description>Number of minutes after which the checkpoint
  gets deleted. If zero, the trash feature is disabled.
  </description>
</property>
```

3) For doing this recovery method  trash should be enabled in hdfs. Trash can be enabled by setting the property  `fs.trash.interval` (as above mentioned xml) greater than 0.

By default the value is zero.  Its value is number of minutes after which the checkpoint gets deleted. If zero, the trash feature is disabled. We have to set this property in core-site.xml.

There is one more property which is having relation with the above property called `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval`. It is the number of minutes between trash checkpoints. This should be smaller or equal to  `fs.trash.interval`.

Everytime the checkpointer runs, it creates a new checkpoint out of current and removes checkpoints created more than `fs.trash.interval` minutes ago.
The default value of this property is zero.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.trash.checkpoint.interval</name>
  <value>15</value>
  <description>Number of minutes between trash checkpoints.
  Should be smaller or equal to fs.trash.interval.
  Every time the checkpointer runs it creates a new checkpoint 
  out of current and removes checkpoints created more than 
  fs.trash.interval minutes ago.
  </description>
</property>
```

If the above properties are enabled in your cluster. Then the deleted files will be present in .Trash directory of hdfs. You have time to recover the files until the next checkpoint occurs. After the new checkpoint the deleted files will not be present in the .Trash. So recover before the new checkpoint. If this property is not enabled in your cluster,  you can enable this for future recovery.. :)

Comment: We don't have directory /user/X, is it configurable, where it is set?

Comment: @MaxNevermind replace X with the current username. Like `hue`, for example

Comment: hmm, looks like "move to trash" works only in console in my case, in hue it doesn't, files won't apear in .Trash folder, probably some settings in hue is not set.